# Why it is showing time limit exceeded?

Tags: c, recursion, time, limit

In the following question I am getting time limit exceeded message on whichever compiler I tried(though they were all online compilers).What should be the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fact(int);
int main(void)
{
    int num,res;
    printf("enter any number");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    res=fact(num);
    printf("%d",res);
    return 0;
}
int fact(int x)
{
    int ans;
    while(x!=1)
        ans=(x*fact(x-1));
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: This very much depends on your input.

Comment: Install a standalone compiler on your machine. This isn't a compile-time, but a runtime problem. Your program compiles fine, but runs for a long time, and this depends on your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that your `fact` function never stopped since `while` loop never ends.

```
int fact(int x)
{
    int ans;
    while(x!=1)
        ans=(x*fact(x-1)); //X is never changed!
    return ans;
}
```

Probably you wanted this:

```
int fact(int x)
{
    int ans = 1; //Set default value for return
    if(x!=1) //Go recursive only if X != 1
        ans=(x*fact(x-1));
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: thanks....but even after doing what u told i am not getting the required output. Though that time limit message has gone

Comment: @kabby what are you getting instead of the required output?

Comment: @kabby Bear in mind that, with a normal 32 bit `int` the largest factorial you can calculate is 12

Comment: @JeremyP when i am giving 5 as input, i am getting 0 as the output

Comment: @kabby Put a print statement just before the return to print both x and ans. That should give you enough to fix the issue. I'm betting you forget to initialise ans with 1.

Comment: oh yes thanks....now it's working fine. but why do we need to initialise ans with 1 even though we are printing it's overwritten value? And why only 1?

Answer (score 1):

It is because your fact function goes into infinite loop.

Assuming you are calculating factorial of a number x, this should be the correct fact function.

```
int fact(int x)
{
    if(x!=1)
        return x*fact(x-1);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int fact(int x)
{
    int ans;
    while(x!=1)
        ans=(x*fact(x-1));
    return ans;
}
```

It is an infinite loop. This is the reason why you get an error as time limit exceeded.
Replace the loop to an if condition:

```
int fact(int x)
{
    int ans = 1;
    if(x!=1)
        ans=(x*fact(x-1));
    return ans;
}
```